# How to store override method in a variable in Scala

Tags: scala

Here is My Code Snippet

```
package SimpleDruidOperation
import java.sql.{Connection, Driver, DriverManager, SQLException, Statement}
class ConnectionEstablishment {
  var conn:Connection=_
  var dr:Driver=_
  def connEstablishment() =
  {
    try {
      dr = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver()
      DriverManager.registerDriver(dr)
      conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/deven","root","root")
      if(conn!=null)
        println("!!Database Connected Succesfully!!!")
      else
        println("!!Check your Database Connection !!")
    }
    catch
      {
        case e:SQLException=>println("Exception is "+e.getMessage)
      }
    finally
      {
        conn.close()
      }
  }
}
class InsertintoDatabase extends ConnectionEstablishment {
  var stmt:Statement=_
  // override def connEstablishment():co = super.connEstablishment()
  val conn:Connection=connEstablishment()//it is not going to override
  def insertintoDatabase(): Unit =
  {
    println("Checking Conection Establishment")
    try {
      stmt = conn1.createStatement()
      var sql = "insert into emp (eid,ename,eadd,emob) values (101,'Mohit','Pune',9156369938) "
      var i = stmt.executeUpdate(sql)
      if (i > 0)
        println(i + "Value Inserted Successfully into Databaes")
      else
        println("!!Not Inserted Check something is going wrong!!")
    }
    catch
      {
        case e:SQLException=>println("Exception is "+e.getMessage)
      }
    finally
    {
      println("Closing Connection Establishment "+conn1.close())
      println("CLosing Statement Connection  "+conn1.close())
    }
  }
}
```

### How to store override method in a variable in Scala

Here in my first class `ConnectionEstablishment` this class is to make connection and second class is for insert into database but the problem is I am unable to override the `connEstablisment` method because if I want override it then I am unable to establish a connection for insert 
because I need it, so that i can call statement `stmt=conn,createStatement()`.

How can I do it?

Comment: You probably don't want to close the connection in the `connEstablishment` function. How will you use it afterwards?

Comment: Yeah @Kraylog I have already done it by using java for ex If w have define a class for connection Now for various types of crud operation I can use it separately No need to connect Database always .We just use that method and automatically it wil take all the methods of connection class

Comment: ex In Java we can write like

Comment: Connection conn=getConnection()// this method I have Define lets Say in Connectionestablishment .Now we can just call that method

Comment: But here In my case in Scala same thing I am using it with Scala but it wont work with this concept .So how can I do it

Comment: You can do everything you can in Java with Scala. The problem is what Kraylog says.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have created a class hierarchy when you actually need two separate classes. The `ConnectionEstablishment` class represents a database connection and the `InsertintoDatabase` class represents an operation on that database, and there is no natural hierarchy between them.

Class hierarchies should have an "is a" relationship: If `D` inherits from `C` then it should make sense to say that a `D` *is a* `C`. So it makes sense for `Circle` to inherit from `Shape` because a circle *is a* shape. It does not make sense for a database operation to inherit from a database connection because a database operation *is not a* database connection.

A database operation *needs a* database connection, and this is a containment relationship, not a hierarchy.

So you should have a `ConnectionEstablishment` class that creates and manages the database connection, and an `InsertintoDatabase` class that takes a `ConnectionEstablishment` instance and uses it to insert items into the database.

With this arrangement you can create different subclasses of `ConnectionEstablishment` that connect to the database in different ways, and the `InsertintoDatabase` class will work with any of those subclasses. Likewise you can create new classes that use the database connection, such as `DeleteFromDatabase`, without having to inherit from the existing `InsertintoDatabase` class.